# Formatação de data em Node.JS, com Sequelize e Moment.JS

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Gostaria de formatar uma data que está sendo carregada do banco de dados com Sequelize. Estou fazendo um blog e preciso pegar a data de criação do artigo

Minha rota:

```
app.get("/", (req,res) =>{
    Article.findAll({
        order:[
            ['id','DESC']
        ],
        limit:6
    }).then(articles =>{
        Category.findAll().then(categories =>{
            res.render("index.ejs", {articles:articles, categories:categories})
        })
    })
})
```

No meu "INDEX.EJS", estou fazendo o forEach dos artigos:

```
        <% articles.forEach(articles => {%>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h2><%= articles.title%></h2>
            
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="card-body" >
            <%- articles.img%>
            <h5><%= articles.subtitle%></h5>
            <h5 id="displayMoment"><%= articles.createdAt%></h5>
            <a href="/<%= articles.slug%>" class="btn btn-success">Ler artigo</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
<% })%>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function()
{
  var NowMoment = moment().format('LLL');

  var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
  eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = NowMoment;  
})();
</script>
```

Ele está retornando a data atual, não a data de criação dos artigos.
Gostaria mais de saber como passa essa variável do createdAt dentro do moment()

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está usando `moment()`.

Para formatar a data de criação do projeto, é preciso que você informe a mesma ao moment através do parâmetro.

Por exemplo:

```
(function()
{
  var NowMoment = moment("<%= articles.createdAt %>").format('LLL');

  var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
  eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = NowMoment;  
})();
```

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso, mas ele retorna como data inválida